# Unusual error using read_csv and col_select and id argument in R

Tags: r, readr

I have a strange error when I try to use the `id` argument `read_csv` together with the `col_select()` but only if I refer to the columns using their numeric position in a *non-continuous* way (eg. c(1:2,4)).

Specifically when you import multiple csv files from a file path using readr::read_csv and use the `id` argument *and* use the `col_select` argument by referencing the columns by **position** in a a non-continuous way then there is an error.

However if we delete the `id` argument, reference the columns by position without "gaps" or even reference the columns by name then it will work.

Is there a way to fix this? or is this a bug?

Please see below:

```
#pretend this file file path has at least two csv files in it
files <- "insert_file_path"

#this will not work, notice there is a "gap" in the refernece (no column 3)
##the error suggest it can't subset columns that don't exist

read_csv(files,
         id = "source",
         col_select = c(1:2,4),#notice that I do not pull in the 3rd column
         )

#this will work now that I references without any "gaps"

read_csv(files,
         id = "source",
         col_select = c(1:3,4) #however it will work when I pull in columns in a continuous way
         )

#howewever if we remove the "id" argument, the below code will work (even though there is a "gap")

read_csv(files,
         #id = "source",
         col_select = c(1:2,4),#however this will work (pulls in different columns though)
         )
```

Comment: Not knowing if this is by design or a bug you might want to check directly with the developers and open a bug report there: https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have submitted the below as an issue on readr and it has been labeled as a bug.

https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/1395